# mpv: How to play audio with SRT subtitles?

Tags: audio, subtitles, mpv

Is there a way to get `mpv` to display external `.srt` subtitles with *audio* files?

In `vlc` this can be achieved by enabling Audio > Visualizations > Spectrometer, and then in advanced Settings under Audio > Visualizations > Visualizer removing all the visual effects so that only the subtitles are displayed.

Is there some similar way or workaround to have subtitles displayed in `mpv`?

Answer (score 3):

If the audio has an embedded cover art then `mpv` will automatically show a window for the cover image, unless this behaviour is explicitly suppressed with `--audio-display=no`. The display window will show whatever subtitles have been detected automatically based on the subtitle load policy that can be set via:

```bash
 --sub-auto=<no|exact|fuzzy|all>
# the default value: exact
```

If the audio file has no cover art then a window can be forced with:

```sh
mpv --force-window some-audio.mp3
```

The command above will automatically display subtitles if the subtitle file is named `some-audio.srt` or `some-audio.vtt` etc.

To load subtitles from a custom file you can use:

```bash
mpv --force-window --sub-files=123.srt some-audio.mp3
```